# How do I compare cell values of a raster with previous cells of this raster? binary r

Tags: r, loops, matrix, binary, raster

I'm pretty new and a beginner in using R.
That's my Problem:

I have a large raster with lots of cells. It's a binary raster, so there are just 0s and 1s. I have to go through the whole raster and find the 0s. If cell [i,j] is a 0, then I need to look pairwise at its 4 neighbours.

I just wanted to try this with a small 7x7 Matrix.

My idea was to use a loop like this:

```
nr3=0
for (i in 1:7)
  {for (j in 1:7)
    {if (m[i,j]==0)
        {if (m[i-1,j]!=0&&m[i,j-1]!=0)
           {nr3++}
         if (m[i-1,j]!=0&&m[i,j+1]!=0)
           {nr3++}
         if (m[i,j+1]!=0&&m[i+1,j]!=0)
           {nr3++}
         if (m[i+1,j]!=0&&m[i,j-1]!=0)
           {nr3++} }}}
```

so that's what it has to be. 
but there is this error:

```
Error in if (m[i-1,j]!=0&&m[i,j-1]!=0 {: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I can see the problem. At the boundary you can't compare all the neighbours. 
That's why I tried that with

```
for (i in 2:6)
for (j in 2:6)
```

It worked. But the Problem is that some are missing.

So what could I do? 
By the way, I hope there is another possibility to solve this task. Maybe I don't need a Loop? I can image that this is not a very good solution for a very large raster.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "need to look pairwise at its 4 neighbours".. what are you looking at them for? what output do you expect? It's better to state this in words, rather than make us work out your intention from your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the `raster` library. This should be faster than your loop approach:

**Dummy Matrix**

```
library(raster)

  #create a dummy raster
  m <- raster(matrix(c(0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0), nrow=3))

    > as.matrix(m)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    1
[3,]    1    1    0
```

**Focal window with 4 neighbours**

```
#define the size of your moving window (focal)
f <- matrix(c(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0), nrow=3)
```

**Use function raster::focal**

for the pairwise comparison and a `<<-` assignment:

```
nr3 <- 0

  focal(m, 
        w   = f, 
        pad = T,
        padValue = 0,
        fun = function(x){
                #x[5] corresponds to the center pixel in the moving window
                if(x[5]==0){

                   #x[2],x[4],x[6] and x[8] are the four neighbours
                   if(x[2]!=0 & x[4]!=0){
                     nr3 <<- nr3 + 1
                   }
                   if(x[8]!=0 & x[4]!=0){
                     nr3 <<- nr3 + 1
                   }
                   if(x[8]!=0 & x[6]!=0){
                     nr3 <<- nr3 + 1
                   }
                   if(x[2]!=0 & x[6]!=0){
                     nr3 <<- nr3 + 1
                   }
                }
        }
    )
```

**Output:**

```
> nr3
[1] 3
```

**Note:**
You have to use the `<<-` assignment here to be able to modify a variable outside the functions environment. To quote [Hadley](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html):

> The regular assignment arrow, `<-`, always creates a variable in the
>   current environment. The deep assignment arrow, `<<-` , never creates a
>   variable in the current environment, but instead modifies an existing
>   variable found by walking up the parent environments.